# SQLite: How insert document with not whole fill columns?

Tags: java, sqlite

In my java aplication I use SQLite.
I have table with 62 columns.
And here code that try to insert document in this table.

```
@Override
protected int insertToDB(Connection connection, String tableName, int pkDocsID, Map < Integer, String > fieldMap) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        String parametersAsQMarks = DBManager.getInsertParametersAsQMarks(fieldMap.size() + COUNT_RESERVED_FIELDS);
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (" + parametersAsQMarks + ")");
        ps.setInt(COUNT_RESERVED_FIELDS, pkDocsID); // reserved field
        int step = COUNT_RESERVED_FIELDS + 1;
        for (int index = 0; index < fieldMap.size(); index++) {
            String fieldValue = fieldMap.get(index + 1);
            ps.setString(index + step, fieldValue);
        }
        return ps.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get error:

```
 [java] [23.01.2018 20:57:28.312] 

md.deeplace.ca.db.SQLiteStrategy.insertM2Document(SQLiteStrategy.java:125) ERROR:
     [java]     table OUTDocsBS has 62 columns but 37 values were supplied
     [java] java.sql.SQLException: table OUTDocsBS has 62 columns but 37 values were supplied
     [java]     at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
     [java]     at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:115)
     [java]     at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
     [java]     at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
     [java]     at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
     [java]     at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
     [java]     at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
     [java]     at com.myproject.ca.db.SQLiteStrategy.insertToDB(SQLiteStrategy.java:64)
```

I want to insert document when fill not all columns. In this case -  37 columns. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to name the columns.  Instead of:

```
..."INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (" + parametersAsQMarks + ")");
```

try

```
..."INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(columnName1, columnName2, ... columnName37) VALUES (" + parametersAsQMarks + ")");
```

where each named column matches the corresponding `fieldMap` value to be inserted.  Based on the code, it might be useful to change `fieldMap` to `Map<String, String>`, where the key is the column name (instead of column number).

Of course, the other remaining columns must allow null.